# emacs - scroll past top of buffer?

Tags: emacs, elisp, centering

Emacs (and all other text editors) by default show blank space below the bottom lines of a buffer. I want emacs to be able to also scroll above/show blank space like this **above** the top lines in a buffer as well so that the top lines can be viewed in the center of the screen for small files.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in Emacs. But perhaps someone will provide an answer saying how to do it. ;-)

Comment: Have you checked this mode https://github.com/emacsmirror/centered-cursor-mode ?

Comment: Yeah, I like centered-cursor-mode, I use it here and there. It doesn't center the cursor at the top of a file though from what I've seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With guidance from [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/261142/thomas)'s answer here I have created a minor mode for this which is now available on MELPA:

[TopSpace](https://github.com/trevorpogue/topspace) - Recenter line 1 with scrollable upper margin/padding

[image: topspace]

Comment: This is awesome! I came looking for the same thing you did and I so appreciate that you made a solution others could use.

Answer (score 1):

I've started a small minor-mode to accomplish this. However, as first versions go, it's probably buggy, doesn't handle all edge cases (such as e.g., narrowing), and isn't particularly efficient.

Thus, I'd be happy to accept improvements: feel free to directly edit this answer if you can make this code better or to extend it.

```
(defvar vertical-center-num-buffers 0
  "The number of buffers in which `vertical-center-mode' is activated.")

(define-minor-mode vertical-center-mode
  "This minor mode displays the contents of a buffer vertically
centered with respect to the window height. This, of course, only
makes sense for buffers whose content is shorter than the window
height."
  nil
  " vc"
  nil

  ;; is the mode being turned on or off?
  (if vertical-center-mode
  ;; on
  (progn
    ;; keep track of the number of lines in the buffer
    (setq-local vertical-center-num-lines (count-lines (point-min) (point-max)))
    ;; use an overlay to display empty lines at the beginning of the buffer
    (setq-local vertical-center-overlay (make-overlay (point-min) (point-max)))
    ;; initial call to the function that centers the buffer contents
    (vertical-center--lines-changed 0)

    ;; react to changes to the buffer or the window
    (add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook 'vertical-center--kill-buffer)
    (add-hook 'window-size-change-functions 'vertical-center--window-size-changed)
    (when (= vertical-center-num-buffers 0)
      (add-hook 'before-change-functions 'vertical-center--before-change)
      (add-hook 'after-change-functions 'vertical-center--after-change))

    ;; this is just to play nice and remove the above hook
    ;; functions when they're no longer needed. Let's keep our
    ;; fingers crossed that we'll always stay in sync.
    (setq vertical-center-num-buffers (1+ vertical-center-num-buffers)))

;; off
;; delete/unset data structures when the mode is turned off
(delete-overlay vertical-center-overlay)
(makunbound 'vertical-center-num-lines)
(makunbound 'vertical-center-overlay)
(setq vertical-center-num-buffers (1- vertical-center-num-buffers))

;; remove hook functions when they're no longer needed
(when (= vertical-center-num-buffers 0)
  (remove-hook 'kill-buffer-hook 'vertical-center--kill-buffer)
  (remove-hook 'window-size-change-functions 'vertical-center--window-size-changed)
  (remove-hook 'before-change-functions 'vertical-center--before-change)
  (remove-hook 'after-change-functions 'vertical-center--after-change))))

;; handle killing of buffers
(defun vertical-center--kill-buffer ()
  (when vertical-center-mode
(setq vertical-center-num-buffers (1- vertical-center-num-buffers))))    

;; react to changes in the window height
(defun vertical-center--window-size-changed (arg)
  (vertical-center--lines-changed 0))

;; handle deletions of buffer text
(defun vertical-center--before-change (beginning end)
  (when (boundp 'vertical-center-num-lines)
(let ((num-lines 0))
  (while (< beginning end)
    (when (= (char-after beginning) ?\n)
      (setq num-lines (1- num-lines)))
    (setq beginning (1+ beginning)))
  (when (< num-lines 0)
    (vertical-center--lines-changed num-lines)))))

;; handle insertions into the buffer
(defun vertical-center--after-change (beginning end previous-length)
  (when (boundp 'vertical-center-num-lines)
(let ((num-lines 0))
  (while (< beginning end)
    (when (= (char-after beginning) ?\n)
      (setq num-lines (1+ num-lines)))
    (setq beginning (1+ beginning)))
  (when (> num-lines 0)
    (vertical-center--lines-changed num-lines)))))

;; update the display when either the buffer content or the window
;; height has changed
(defun vertical-center--lines-changed (num-lines)
  (setq vertical-center-num-lines (+ vertical-center-num-lines num-lines))
  (let ((top-margin (/ (- (window-height) vertical-center-num-lines) 2)))
    ;; set the top margin
    (overlay-put vertical-center-overlay 'before-string 
             (when (> top-margin 0)
               (make-string top-margin ?\n)))))
```

Save the above code in a file named `"vertical-center.el"` in a directory of your choice, and then add the following lines to your [`.emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) file:

```
(setq load-path (append load-path "<directory>"))
(autoload 'vertical-center-mode "vertical-center")
```

Here, `<directory>` should be the path to the directory in which you saved the `"vertical-center.el"` file.

After restarting Emacs, you can now activate or deactivate the mode by typing <kbd>M-x vertical-center-mode</kbd>.

Comment: Awesome thanks! This is the first solution I've seen for this. For me, I wanted to be able to "scroll above the top margin" in both big and small files, and just manually control the scrolling - i.e. not worrying about the file always being re-centered after every edit etc. To do this, I removed the above hooks except for the `kill-buffer-hook`, created & added a custom hook in this minor mode which triggers the `vertical-center--lines-changed` function. I then have my scrolling keybindings also run the custom hook to increase or decrease the overlay size depending on the scroll direction.

Comment: Sounds amazing. Do you think there is a way to combine your version of the code and mine, allowing the user to configure whether they want auto-centering or simply scrolling? Is your code available somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, I was able to integrate the scrolling ability with your version and put in an edit request to this answer with the updated code yesterday. I made some fairly major code changes and I'm not sure how long it takes for the edit to be reviewed. Perhaps this type of work is better suited on a version control platform. Let me know if you would be interested in collaborating on this in a github repo instead.

Comment: Sure, put it on github.

Comment: Okay, see the github repo [here](https://github.com/trevorpogue/vertical-center-mode).

Comment: Hi @Thomas, just to let you know, I've recently polished up my minor mode for this and it's now available on MELPA (see the link in my answer to this question). Thanks for the help!